# Does PyPy or Jython run untrusted Python 3 code more secure while still being fast?

Tags: python, interpreters, python-3.x

I know that one can not securely restrict normal CPython's capabilities to properly run foreign code without allowing it to access some builtins like `open()` or allowing other kinds of I/O.

So I researched more and found the alternative interpreters PyPy (written in Python) and Jython (written in Java). **Which of those is easier to use for sandboxing user scripts that must interact with the core application?**

---

Here's a short description of what my program should do and what is important for me:

The program will be a multiplayer game that may be run on any PC as server and which allows any number of clients to connect locally or over the network. The game is a round-based normal strategy (mine resources, develop a strong base, conquer territories, eliminate enemies) game, but units should not be controlled directly via mouse/keyboard, but only through Python scripts and commands which the players may upload to the server and that are run each round to determine the actions. The idea for this project comes from http://screeps.com, but I would not like to make an exact clone but just something similar...

Important points are:

- *secure sandboxing* of the user scripts. I want that the users should write a class derived from a given subclass which has functions to access the game core. There should be no chance to perform any I/O or system access other than through those methods. Imports must be restricted to tools like `string` and `math` only, no possibly dangerous stuff like `os` or `subprocess`.
- *good support for real multi-threading*, as I should run as many user scripts in parallel as possible to keep the round durations short.
- The interpreter should be fast and lightweight enough to handle quite a few clients in parallel. I also need an efficient database access with intelligent caching (probably have to code that myself?) that speeds up the data access times without flooding the RAM.

I also know Java fairly well, so I could possibly also write parts of the game core in Java if that could speed things up or make them more secure, but I want the user scripts to be in Python 3.

---

So again, which Python interpreter would be most suitable for this task? What (dis)advantages does each one have with respect to the listed requirements?

Comment: May I ask the downvoter to explain his vote and help me to improve the question? Thanks.

Comment: @Tibo I don't understand your critique. First, I am a person who does not want to pay. Second, I like coding. Third, I am not exactly cloning them, but trying to make my own game derived from their idea. It will use a different language for the scripts and I hope to be able to add more features and customize it as soon as I have a working core. Fourth, it's a great chance to dive even deeper into Python and maybe also Java and to gain more experience with different situations. And fifth, I am looking for a free time project currently anyway and this sounded interesting.

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat I would not really see my question as software recommendation, I am specifically asking for the (dis)advantages of those two interpreters regarding to a list of my personal requirements which are detailedly explained. I don't think this question can generate too opinion-based answers.

Comment: "recommended interpreter?" -- if this is not asking for software recommendations then I don't know what is

Comment: Did you only read the title or the entire question? But anyway, I edited the title. Better now? @gnat

Comment: sure, both title and text: "which Python interpreter would be most suitable for this task?"

Comment: @gnat Okay, but that's not broadly asking "how do I run insecure code", but "which of PyPy and Jython are better suited for that task with respect to that list of other requirements". One can surely write a good and facts-based answer on that, outlining each interpreter's (dis)advantages in those categories and drawing a conclusion from that. That is, if this one isn't busy finding close reasons...

Comment: @ByteCommander: Ah, I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. I thought the website was yours. The idea is great, as I said, and your question really makes sense. However, don't call the project "template", as what you are doing is a clone.

Comment: @Tibo Ah, I see. Edited that part. Shall we delete our comments about that to clean up a bit?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I know that in general, when running untrusted code this way, controlling access to the underlying infrastructure is only half the job, another part is to limit the memory and CPU resources available to it. Java isn't great at those things.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks for the first constructive comment to this question! :)